# seqecreate reorders events alphabetically

Tags: r, traminer

I am creating an event sequence using Traminer seqecreate function. However, the events that occur at the same time are reordered alphabetically in created the event sequence object.

The data is ordered by sequence of occurring events however on creating the event sequence object the events taking place at the same time are reordered alphabetically.

I can manually combine events that happen at the same time, however just wanted to ask how to ensure seqecreate doesn't reorder the events

```
library("dplyr")
library("TraMineR")
# DATA
eventDat <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,10), rep(3,12)),
                        timeframe = c(rep(0,3),1,rep(0,3),rep(458,3),rep(558,2),559,560,
                                      rep(0,3),8,rep(48,3),57,169,170,511,546),
                        event = c("I01,I02,I03,I17,I05,I16","T222,T511,T30,T12","noProc",
                                  "apcdischarge","I01","T222,T221,T53","aedischarge",
                                  "I03,I05,I06","T222,T511,T30,T17","aedischarge",
                                  "I01,I02,I03,I05,I16,I14,I17,I07,I06",
                                  "T222,T516,T291,T30","M472","apcdischarge",
                                  "I01,I02,I05,I03","T12,T25,T30,T222,T291",
                                  "noProc","apcdischarge","I01,I02,I05,I03,I17",
                                  "T222,T221,T511,T30","noProc","apcdischarge",
                                  "noProc","apcdischarge","E852,E851,U201","apcdischarge"
                        ))


seqDat<- seqecreate(id=eventDat$id, 
                  timestamp=eventDat$timeframe,
                  event=eventDat$event)

seqDat[1]

#Warning message:
# In seqecreate.internal(data = data, id = id, timestamp = timestamp,  :
# [!] some of your events contain '(', ')' or ',' characters. 
# The search of specific subsequences may not work properly.

# remove commas
# Fix events contain '(', ')' or ',' characters
eventDat <- eventDat %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(eventF = paste0(trimws(strsplit(as.character(event), ",")[[1]], "b"), 
                        collapse = "."))

#order by ID and time frame
eventDat <- eventDat %>%
  arrange(id, timeframe)

seqDat<- seqecreate(id=eventDat$id, 
                    timestamp=eventDat$timeframe,
                    event=eventDat$eventF)
seqDat[1]
```

The output being produced is

```
(I01.I02.I03.I17.I05.I16,noProc,T222.T511.T30.T12)-1-(apcdischarge)
```

However I expect

```
(I01.I02.I03.I17.I05.I16,T222.T511.T30.T12,noProc)-1-(apcdischarge)
```

Comment: `eventDat$event` is a factor so R treats `noProc` as a factor level. Would it be sufficient to remove all occurrences of `noProc` after using `seqecreate()`?

Comment: noProc is one of the events of interest. The events are ordered by occurrence in the data however seqecreate() reorders the events when creating the event sequence object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not a factor, the `event` argument of `seqecreate` is coerced into a factor by ordering the levels alphabetically by default. You can set your own order by the passing a self defined factor with the wanted level order as event argument.

I illustrate with your example:

We retrieve the current level order and set the "noProc" event as the last element

```
ev.list <- levels(factor(eventDat$eventF))
ev.alph <- c(ev.list[ev.list!="noProc"],"noProc")
```

Now we define the factor using the wanted order of the alphabet of events and pass it as `event` argument

```
event <- factor(eventDat$eventF, levels=ev.alph)  
seqDat<- seqecreate(id=eventDat$id, 
                    timestamp=eventDat$timeframe,
                    event=event)
seqDat[1]

## [1] (I01.I02.I03.I17.I05.I16,T222.T511.T30.T12,noProc)-1-(apcdischarge)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however noProc is not always the last event for example: seqDat [2]. I think I can set the level order because I have three known end points. however in cases where for instance I had not coded the events beginning with I and T as such it would be difficult to set the level as the order varies in the data

Comment: The idea is to set an order of the alphabet (set of events) for the event sequence  object (i.e. valid for all the sequences). The events forming a transition will then be displayed according to that order whatever the sequence. Setting `noProc` as the last element is just an example. You can set the order of the elements forming the alphabet as you want. Simply define the `ev.alph` vector you want.